It is not possible to save data to a table(H2 DataBase) using Spring-Data-JPA
I am using H2 database version 2.2.224 and Spring-Data-JPA version 3.3.3. I have a Many-to-Many relationship between the "USERS" and "ROLES" tables.
When I try to save "Entity = USERS" to the H2 Database, I get the following error::
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Generated column "PUBLIC.USERS.USER_ID_PK" cannot be assigned.
SQL statement: insert into users (password,login,user_id_pk) values (?,?,?) [90154-224]
In my opinion, this error occurs due to the fact that Spring JPA generates the id itself and tries to insert this id into the database itself, while H2 wants to generate the id itself and insert it into the table.
If I create the "user_id_pk" column in the "USERS" table like this:: "user_id_pk integer PRIMARY KEY" and change the GenerationType in "Entity = USERS", then various errors occur.

GenerationType.AUTO :: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Roles
GenerationType.SEQUENCE:: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Roles
GenerationType.IDENTITY:: JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "USER_ID_PK";

If I create the column "user_id_pk" in the "USERS" table like this:: role_id_pk integer GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY and change GenerationType in "Entity = USERS", then various errors occur.

GenerationType.AUTO :: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Roles
GenerationType.SEQUENCE:: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Roles
GenerationType.IDENTITY:: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Roles

If I create the column "user_id_pk" in the "USERS" table like this:: role_id_pk integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY and change GenerationType in "Entity = USERS", then various errors occur.

GenerationType.AUTO :: Generated column "PUBLIC.USERS.USER_ID_PK" cannot be assigned
GenerationType.SEQUENCE:: Generated column "PUBLIC.USERS.USER_ID_PK" cannot be assigned
GenerationType.IDENTITY:: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Roles

I create a SEQUENCE like this::
CREATE SEQUENCE USERS_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 50;

My Tables::
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.ROLES (
   role_id_pk Integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
   role VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.USERS (
   user_id_pk Integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
   login VARCHAR, 
   password VARCHAR
);

My Entity::
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class MyUser {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id_pk")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "login")
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "USERS_ROLES",
           joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id_pk")},
           inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "role_id_pk")})
private List<Roles> listRoles;

My Entity::
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Roles {

 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 @Column(name = "role_id_pk")
 private Long id;

 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 @Column(length = 20, name = "role")
 private ERole name;

 @ManyToMany(mappedBy="listRoles")
 private List<MyUser> myUsersList;


The first error that you mention  Generated column "PUBLIC.USERS.USER_ID_PK" cannot be assigned happens because you are trying to assign a value to a generated column (Link to error).
Regarding the error object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: Roles happens because you have the collection listRoles in your entity users, and that collection has items which are not stored in the database. Try adding cascade=CascadeType.ALL on your collection mapping.
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Roles> listRoles;

Note: When implementing a bidirectional many-to-many, JPA creates an intermediate table linking the two Entities.
Here is an example of how they implement the many-to-many relationship (the page is in Spanish, but the code is easy to understand): https://www.oscarblancarteblog.com/2018/12/27/relaciones-manytomany/
I also leave you the different types of generation that Hibernate provides for Ids, so you have more context: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-identifiers

About the error Generated column "PUBLIC.USERS.USER_ID_PK" cannot be assigned:: When I save Entity = MyUser, I only set username and password, that is, I do not set USER_ID_PK with my hands. But the H2 database claims that when saving this MyUser, I set this USER_ID_PK somewhere with my hands and says that H2 itself will generate a value for USER_ID_PK and will not save MyUser. Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

I need more context in that case. Can you tell how you create the objects and save them in the database? By the way, a requirement of JPA is to have at least a default no-argument constructor in you entity classes (link).

@ Jos3lu Here MyUser Entity, Roles Entity, ServiceSignUp Service

@YuraMazurov I created a new spring project and copy-paste what you passed me. Except that you are missing the: @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) in your "listRoles" field, the rest is correct. At least it worked perfectly fine for me.

@YuraMazurov Here are the files that I have created and which have worked well for me: new User h2

@ Jos3lu Thank you so much for your help. I will study your code carefully
